# how to filter out object having different keys in nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I would like to know how to filter out object in a nested array using javascript.
I have obj `sample_obj` in which has different keys, I want to filter using payin=="bank" && payout=="bank" in javascript.

```
   var result= sample_obj.filter((e)=>{
      e.payin=="bank" && e.payout=="bank"
    })
console.log("Result:", result);
//inputs
var sample_obj = [{
  obj1: [{
    id: "IN",
    amount: 100,
    payin: "bank",
    payout: "bank"
  },{
    id: "IN",
    amount: 200,
    payin: "credit",
    payout: "bank"
  }],
  obj2: [{
    id: "TR",
    amount: 120,
    payin: "bank",
    payout: "bank"
  },{
    id: "TR",
    amount: 250,
    payin: "debit",
    payout: "bank"
  }]
}]

 Output:
  Result:[{
    id: "IN",
    amount: 100,
    payin: "bank",
    payout: "bank"
 },    {id: "TR",
    amount: 120,
    payin: "bank",
    payout: "bank"}]
```

Comment: You need to `return` inside filter `return e.payin=="bank" && e.payout=="bank"` OR remove the `{}` wrapper for implicit return

Comment: @adiga thanks for reply, It doesnot work , but my question is since i have two different keys, `obj1` and `obj2` inside `sample_obj`,  how to use filter

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question since `return` is not the only issue with your question. You have a nested arrays inside an object. You need to loop through each property and do the filtering

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the function body `{}`, you need to use `return`. You also need to change a few things due to your data structure:

```js
 

var sample_obj = [{
  obj1: [{
id: "IN",
amount: 100,
payin: "bank",
payout: "bank"
  },{
id: "IN",
amount: 200,
payin: "credit",
payout: "bank"
  }],
  obj2: [{
id: "TR",
amount: 120,
payin: "bank",
payout: "bank"
  },{
id: "TR",
amount: 250,
payin: "debit",
payout: "bank"
  }]
}]

var result= Object.values(sample_obj[0]).
reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr)).filter((e)=>{
  return e.payin=="bank" && e.payout=="bank"
});
console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: thanks for solution, is it possible to do using filter as well?

Comment: That does use filter...